Prove $\ln (1+x) \leq x - x^2/4 $ for $x \leq 1$ using Taylor's theorem
RTP: $\ln (1+x) \leq x - \frac{1}{4} x^2$ for $x \leq 1$
I am trying to prove this specifically using Taylor theorem. Here is what I have so far:
$\ln (1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3(1+\xi)^3}$, where $\xi \in (0, x)$
If $x > 0$ then $\frac{x^3}{3(1+\xi)^3} \leq \frac{x^3}{3}$
If $x < 0$ then $\frac{x^3}{3(1+\xi)^3} \leq \frac{x^3}{3(1+x)^3}$
For $x>0$, we have $\ln (1+x) \leq x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}$
Now I would like to show that $- \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} \leq - \frac{x^2}{4}$, but simply graphing this shows that it isn't true.
Similarly, for $x <0$, we have $\ln (1+x) \leq x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3(1+x)^3}$,
which is again not true for all $x < 0$.
Could anyone help me prove this inequality? Thank you!

For $x>-1$, we have
$$
\log (1 + x) = x - x^2 \int_0^1 {\frac{t}{{1 + xt}}{\rm d}t} .
$$
If $-1<x\le 1$, then
$$
\int_0^1 {\frac{t}{{1 + xt}}{\rm d}t}  \ge \int_0^1 {\frac{t}{{1 + t}}{\rm d}t}  = 1 - \log 2 > \frac{1}{4}.
$$

Thanks for this, though it doesn't fully answer the case for $x < -1$ as the same integral representation wouldn't hold. Do you have a suggestion for what I could try for $x < -1$?

What is $\log(1+x)$ for $x<-1$? The whole question makes sense only if $x>-1$.

Oh, I can't believe that never occurred to me, thanks!
